# Kafka schema registry not compatible in the same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Kafka schema registry for producing/consuming Kafka messages, for example I have two fields they are both string type, the pseudo schema as following：

```
{"name": "test1", "type": "string"}
{"name": "test2", "type": "string"}
```

but after sending and consuming a while, I need modify schema to change the second filed to long type, then it threw the following exception:

```
Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409
```

I'm confused, if schema registry can not evolve the schema upgrade/change, then why should I use Schema registry, or say why I use Avro?

Answer (score 37):

Fields cannot be renamed in `BACKWARD` compatibility mode. As a workaround you can change the compatibility rules for the schema registry.

According to the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/schema-registry/docs/api.html#compatibility):

> The schema registry server can enforce certain compatibility rules
> when new schemas are registered in a subject. Currently, we support
> the following compatibility rules.
>
> **Backward compatibility (default):** A new schema is backward compatible
> if it can be used to read the data written in all previous schemas.
> Backward compatibility is useful for loading data into systems like
> Hadoop since one can always query data of all versions using the
> latest schema.

> **Forward compatibility: A new schema is forward**
> compatible if all previous schemas can read data written in this
> schema. Forward compatibility is useful for consumer applications that
> can only deal with data in a particular version that may not always be
> the latest version.
>
> **Full compatibility:** A new schema is fully
> compatible if it’s both backward and forward compatible.

> **No compatibility:** A new schema can be any schema as long as it’s a valid
> Avro.

Setting `compatibility` to `NONE` should do the trick.

```
# Update compatibility requirements globally
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
    --data '{"compatibility": "NONE"}' \
    http://localhost:8081/config
```

And the response should be

```
{"compatibility":"NONE"}
```

You can also set `compatibility` to `NONE` for a single subject:

```
# Update compatibility requirements for single subject
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
    --data '{"compatibility": "NONE"}' \
    http://localhost:8081/config/subject
```

---

***I generally discourage setting compatibility to `NONE` on a subject unless absolutely necessary.***

Answer (score 22):

If you need just the new schema and you don't need the previous schemas from schema registry, you can delete the older schemas as mentioned below
:

I've tested this with confluent-kafka and it worked for me

#### Deletes all schema versions registered under the subject "Kafka-value"

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/Kafka-value
```

#### Deletes version 1 of the schema registered under subject "Kafka-value"

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/Kafka-value/versions/1
```

#### Deletes the most recently registered schema under subject "Kafka-value"

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/subjects/Kafka-value/versions/latest
```

Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-deletion-guidelines.html

Answer (score 7):

https://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html 
You might need to add a "default": null.

You can also delete existing one and register the updated one.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply append a default value like this.

```
{"name": "test3", "type": "string","default": null}
```

Comment: won't that give you `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Invalid default for field test3: null not a "string"` ?

Comment: Yes it does  Non-string default value for string: null

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/707

Comment: sweet and simple thing for backward compatibility, thanks. works !

Answer (score 0):

On your local environment you can execute this on Postman :

**URL** : http://localhost:8081/config
**Method** : PUT
**Body** :
{
"compatibility": "NONE"
}

This fix solved the problem for me