# FlinkKafkaConsumer/Producer & Confluent Avro schema registry: Validation failed & Compatibility mode writes invalid schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

Hello together im struggling with (de-)serializing a simple avro schema together with schema registry.

The setup:

- 2 Flink jobs written in java (one consumer, one producer)
- 1 confluent schema registry for schema validation
- 1 kafka cluster for messaging

The target:
The producer should send a message serialized with `ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` which includes updating and validating the schema.

The consumer should then deserialize the message into an object with the received schema. Using `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema`.

So far so good:
If i configre my subject on the schema registry to be `FORWARD`-compatible the producer writes the correct avro schema to the registry, but it ends with the error (even if i completely and permanetly delete the subject first):

```
Failed to send data to Kafka: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "my.awesome.MyExampleEntity-value"
```

The schema was successfully written:

```
{
        "subject": "my.awesome.MyExampleEntity-value",
        "version": 1,
        "id": 100028,
        "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"input\",\"namespace\":\"my.awesome.MyExampleEntity\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"serialNumber\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"editingDate\",\"type\":\"int\",\"logicalType\":\"date\"}]}"
}
```

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801055/kafka-schema-registry-not-compatible-in-the-same-topic) i could try to set the `compability` to `NONE`

If i do so i can produce my data on the kafka **but**:
The schema registry has a new version of my schema looking like this:

```
{
        "subject": "my.awesome.MyExampleEntity-value",
        "version": 2,
        "id": 100031,
        "schema": "\"bytes\""
}
```

Now i can produce data but the consumer is not able to deserialize this schema emiting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found bytes, expecting my.awesome.MyExampleEntity
...
```

Im currently not sure where the problem exactly is.
Even if i completely and permanetly delete the subject (including schemas) my producer should work fine from scratch registering a whole "new" subject with schema.
On the other hand if i set the compatibility to "NONE" the schema exchange should work anyway by should registering a schema which can be read by the consumer.

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: What is the property of setting the compatibility mode and where to add this property in the code?

Comment: @Sam you need to set the compability mode on the Schema registry, either per config or rest api. See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html

Comment: How about property schema.compatibility.level given on https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html page?

Comment: schema.compatibility.level didn't work from. did you find a way to set it through flink job during sink ?

Answer (score 1):

According to a latest confluent doc `NONE`: schema compatibility checks are disabled [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#compatibility):

Comment: Where can is set compatibility checks property In my flinkkafka based application?

Comment: @Sam if you still have questions you'd better ask your own question on StackOverflow not in comments. Reading documentation also can help. To set your compatibility see [this example](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/using.html#update-compatibility-requirements-globally)

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem with serialisation was about the usage of the following flag in the kafka config:

```
"schema.registry.url"
"key.serializer"
"key.deserializer"
"value.serializer"
"value.deserializer"
```

Setting this flags in flink, even if they are logically correct leads to a undebuggable schema validation and serialisation chaos.
Omitted all of these flags and it works fine.
The registry url needs to be set in `ConfluentRegistryAvro(De)serializationSchema` only.